# Loop through multiple parameters stored in dataframe in API GET requests then store and append JSON results to dataframe

Tags: python, parameters, python-requests, urllib

I have a pandas dataframe that contains several records representing parameter values for an API GET request.

| paramA | paramB | paramC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | 123 | abc |
| xyy | 122 | abb |

I want to loop through each record to update the parameters in a GET request as shown below.

```
{{HOST}}/client/{{VERSION_CLIENT}}/access_token={{CLIENT_TOKEN}}&paramA=paramA&paramB=paramB&paramC=paramC
```

For each JSON response, I want to store and append the results in a single pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create URLs from the dataframe for example using `zip()` function:

```py
import requests

url = 'HOST/client/VERSION_CLIENT/access_token=CLIENT_TOKEN&paramA={paramA}&paramB={paramB}&paramC={paramC}'

for paramA, paramB, paramC in zip(df['paramA'], df['paramB'], df['paramC']):
    u = url.format(paramA=paramA, paramB=paramB, paramC=paramC)
    print(u)
```

Prints:

```
HOST/client/VERSION_CLIENT/access_token=CLIENT_TOKEN&paramA=xyz&paramB=123&paramC=abc
HOST/client/VERSION_CLIENT/access_token=CLIENT_TOKEN&paramA=xyy&paramB=122&paramC=abb
```

---

To create dataframe from the responses:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'HOST/client/VERSION_CLIENT/access_token=CLIENT_TOKEN&paramA={paramA}&paramB={paramB}&paramC={paramC}'

all_data = []
for paramA, paramB, paramC in zip(df['paramA'], df['paramB'], df['paramC']):
    u = url.format(paramA=paramA, paramB=paramB, paramC=paramC)
    data = requests.get(u).json()
    all_data.append(data)   # <-- or add to `all_data` only information you want from the response

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```